# What is the minimum that has to be backed up on a cryptocurrency wallet (technically)?

Tags: wallet, private-key, backup, seed

Is the seed enough? Doesnt it require the seed AND the adresses to access your assets, since the root key and therefore all private keys are generated by the seed?

Does it generate the private key for each adress by seeding the root key and the adress?

Thanks for any enlightment.

Answer (score 1):

*technically* the *minimum* you must backup are your private keys.

Is the seed enough? if you used a program which generates a wallet by a passphrase/seed it *should* be enough to save the passphrase/seed. test it to be sure.

i don't think you must really backup your public key or adress because it can be generated by your wallet with your private key/passphrase/seed.

Comment: But how does the wallet then know which adresses and key have been generated by the seed?